# UIAlertView Change BackGround Color

Tags: ios, background, uialertview, background-color

Hi I am trying to change the UiAlertview BG color to green, using setBGcolor it give me following output, Which had a dark color Specified in SetBGColor, anyother way to remove the background color or something else.

[image: SetBGcolor OUTPUT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't customize a `UIAlertView`, nor can you can use `appearance` property in this case.
So if you have to do it, what you can do is use a `view` that gives a `UIAlertView`-like display. You can create a custom view with buttons and use it throughout the app.

Or you  can check [this](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView) link. It might help you!

Comment: "No You can't customize" :: How could you be so sure on this?

Comment: From Apple's documentation: "Appearance of Alert Views:
You cannot customize the appearance of alert views."

Answer (score 7):

you can change the image or background of the `UIAlertView` but add some subview to it. [Here](https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView) is link which can be useful for you . I am also posting some images for you from given link. But these files are not working in iOS 7

[image: First image][image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @iEinstein the link you provided is not working ..can you provide code or working link?

Comment: @NarasimhaNallamsetty- Really Brother it don't work after iOS 6