# tintColor of UIActionSheet (or UIAlertView) (iOS 7+)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiactionsheet

Is it possible to have buttons in `UIActionSheet` in iOS 7's `tintColor` color? I mean if my app is in brand `tintColor`, for example red, I don't want blue buttons in action sheet. The same with `UIAlertView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713307/uialertview-change-background-color

Comment: John Riselvato is right in linking to the answer, "No, neither UIAlertView or UIActionSheet are designed by Apple to be subclassed." For custom appearance, you need to roll your own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248400/uiactionsheet-buttons-color/19191489#19191489

Comment: https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet

Answer (score 5):

I want to stress that this violates Apple's rules, but this works:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    [actionSheet.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            NSString *buttonText = button.titleLabel.text;
            if ([buttonText isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)]) {
               [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

(conform to `UIActionSheetDelegate`)

Not tried UIAlertView yet.

Comment: You should be using the following method to update the button title color:
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here is a quick implementation for iOS7:

```
@interface LNActionSheet : UIActionSheet
{
    NSString* _destructiveButtonTitle;
    UIColor* _customtintColor;
}

@end

@implementation LNActionSheet

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:title delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];

    if(self)
    {
        va_list list;
        va_start(list, otherButtonTitles);

        for(NSString* title = otherButtonTitles; title != nil; title = va_arg(list, NSString*))
        {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:title];
        }

        va_end(list);

        _destructiveButtonTitle = destructiveButtonTitle;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    _customtintColor = tintColor;
}

-(void)tintColorDidChange
{
    [super tintColorDidChange];

    for(id subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton* button = subview;

            if(![button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:_destructiveButtonTitle])
            {
                [button setTitleColor:_customtintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Before showing, set the tint color of the action sheet to your liking.

In this implementation, I have elected to keep the destructive button title as red, but this can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my child class UICustomActionSheet. 
I've just pushed the latest changes, which allow to display styling correctly for iOs6 and iOs7 design.
https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet

You can set the colors, fonts, text colors and also images for each buttons. Works fine both for iPhone and iPad. Component is absolutely safety for Appstore so you can use it in your applications. Enjoy!